# Aligning Flex popup

Tags: css, flash, apache-flex, adobe

I have a title window in adobe flex starting like .I am beginner in flex .

```
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
                                xmlns:mate="http://mate.asfusion.com/" 
                                width="190" height="350" 
                                creationComplete="initDefaultMic()" 
                                styleName="micSettingsWindowStyle"
                                showCloseButton="false"
                                verticalCenter="10" horizontalCenter="10" 
                                close="onCancelClicked()" 
                                keyDown="handleKeyDown(event)">
```

I  have given  `verticalCenter="10" horizontalCenter="10"`   and expecting this should align
accordingly instead of aligning centrally.
But every time it is aligning centrally .I have tried clearing browser cache also .

Here is the logic of pop creation using manager

```
   var micWarning:MicWarning = new MicWarning();
   micWarning.micsettings = this;
   PopUpManager.addPopUp(micWarning, this, true);
  // PopUpManager.centerPopUp(micWarning);
```

Please suggest me what might I am doing wrong .

I tried defining x and y coordinates also but that also doesn't work .

Answer (score 0):

verticalCenter="10" and horizontalCenter="10" don't working.

I propose to do something like that

```
var micWarning:MicWarning = new MicWarning();
var verticalCenter:int = 10;
var horizontalCenter:int = 10;
micWarning.x = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.width / 2 - micWarning.width / 2 + verticalCenter;
micWarning.y = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.height / 2 - micWarning.height / 2 + horizontalCenter;
PopUpManager.addPopUp(micWarning, FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as DisplayObject, true);
```

Comment: var verticalCenter:int = 100;
var horizontalCenter:int = 100; maybe 10 very low value and you simple doesn't see any difference

Comment: Check your code, may be your calls centerPopUp after positionig window, because by default window shows at the top left corner.